# Get both the old and new zoom values in OpenLayers 4

Tags: openlayers

In an OpenLayers 4 application, I want to refresh the view of a layer when the user crosses a particular zoom level, either zooming in or zooming out (the tile rendering changes at that point from less to more complex or vice versa).

I can capture `change:resolution`, and get the new value, but is there a way of getting the old value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is in the answer :)

If you look the [View API](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html) for `change resolution`, you will see that it's emit [an event](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Object.Event.html) The description states the following

**oldValue{*}**

The old value. To get the new value use e.target.get(e.key) where e is the event object.

Just applied the recipe to get what you want.

I've also considered another approach using `movestart`, `movend` map events.
Both provided solutions are not the "silver bullet" as you will see in [this demo](https://bl.ocks.org/ThomasG77/f1634b7e22626f6485db0a73e5843381)

To better understand, in the demo, open the browser debugger (I use some `console.log`) and look at source comments. I explained here the issues I got with both approaches.
There is maybe a better way but I did not found it at the moment.